# Overwritten Recovery Partition on Moto G Falcon

Tags: adb

My 2013 Moto G (falcon) was running Lineage fine, but I decided to 'fix it'!

OK - I wanted to try another build, but in flashing I've overwritten TWRP on the recovery partition, so I can't do anything now. I've got ADB installed on my Linux laptop.

I'd be grateful for any ideas, please.

Jim

Comment: You just need to boot into fastboot mode and use `fastboot` to flash TWRP again, the same way you did the first time you installed TWRP. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to restore TWRP to the recovery partition.

The first option, and probably the most common, is to reflash it with fastboot.

First, make sure you have fastboot installed (adb does nothing here), and then download the latest TWRP image file for your device from the official site: https://twrp.me/motorola/motorolamotog2013.html

The file you are looking for is `twrp-3.2.3-0-falcon.img` and place it in a known location.

Now shutdown the device completely, and hold POWER and VOL DN to start the bootloader, then a USB cable from your phone to the computer.

Open a terminal window, and navigate to the directory containing the TWRP image file, and enter the following command:

`sudo fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.2.3-0-falcon.img`

Enter your password, then wait for the process to complete, and use the volume keys to select Start Recovery, and press Power to start TWRP.

The other option if you have a bootable, rooted device, is to install the [official TWRP app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twrp.twrpapp), and install it from there.

Comment: Great - it did the trick. I promise to be more careful from now on! Thanks again. Jim

Comment: @JimFord Awesome! Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted so the question can be closed.